# if I enter a float value and try to convert it to int, I get an error

Tags: python

I am getting a value error  when I try to enter 10.8 as hours. Why can't I enter a float value and convert it into int here?

```
def computepay(hours,rate):
    try:
        hours=int(hours)
        rate=float(rate)
        if hours > 40:
            payment = 40 * rate # Standard Payment until 40 Hours
            payment = payment + rate *(hours-40) * 1.5  # + the rest which has more rate
            print("Pay:",payment)
        else:
            payment=hours*rate
            print("Pay:", payment) # Otherwise Normal Payment
    except:
        print("Value error")


hours=input("Enter hours:")
rate=input("Enter Rate:")
computepay(hours,rate)
```

Comment: Give the full error you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply because `int()` cannot convert strings that do not represent integers. As input returns as string, I suggest you pass it to `float()` first.

So : `hours = int(float(hours))`.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make much sense of the code but it appears that you are passing `string` values to the method directly. `input()` returns a string. In your case putting in 10.8 would produce a

> ValueError, invalid literal with base 10.

What you should be doing is casting your input into a float and then passing it to your function.
Do something like this.

```
hours = float(input("Enter hours:"))
rate = float(input("Enter Rate:"))
computepay(hours,rate)
```